# Visualize Table in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How can I visualize this data as table in SwiftUI:

I have an invoice object with pages and tables and cells.

The cells do have information about rowIndex and columnIndex:

```
struct Cell: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let rowIndex, columnIndex: Int
    let text: String
    let boundingBox: [Double]
    let isHeader: Bool?
}
```

Currently I have no better idea then this do get a "new" row:

```
if !invoice.invoice.isEmpty {
    ScrollView{
        HStack {
            ForEach (invoice.invoice) {invoice in
                ForEach (invoice.analyzeResult.pageResults) {pageresult in
                    ForEach (pageresult.tables) {table in
                        ForEach (table.cells) {cell in
                            if (cell.rowIndex == 0) {
                                Text(cell.text)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        HStack {
            ForEach (invoice.invoice) {invoice in
                ForEach (invoice.analyzeResult.pageResults) {pageresult in
                    ForEach (pageresult.tables) {table in
                        ForEach (table.cells) {cell in
                            if (cell.rowIndex == 1) {
                                Text(cell.text)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: do you know the nr of columns & rows of your data?

Comment: Yes, i know both. I have two fields giving me the total amount of rows and columns.

Comment: This likely isn't good design but you can tie a `LazyVGrid`/`LazyHGrid` tied to a Dimensional array (sudoku style) and insert the cell to that array. I hesitate implementing loops of any kind since the column and row are hardcoded and you would have to plan for "missing" values. If there is no chance of missing values you can sort the array by the columns, and rows and implement a `LazyVGrid` but it only works if your data is perfect, it is a very fragile setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a combination of VStack and HStack or a LazyVGrid, the latter seems more appropriate. In both cases you have to find the nr of columns (and rows for 1. case).

Here is an example with both approaches:

```
// create dummy data
let tableData: [Cell] = {
    var result = [Cell]()
    for row in 0..<10 {
        for col in 0..<5 {
            result.append(Cell(rowIndex: row, columnIndex: col, text: "cell \(row), \(col)", boundingBox: [], isHeader: nil))
        }
    }
    return result
}()


struct ContentView: View {
    // find row & col nrs
    let rowNr = tableData.max(by: {$0.rowIndex < $1.rowIndex})?.rowIndex ?? 0
    let colNr = tableData.max(by: {$0.columnIndex < $1.columnIndex})?.columnIndex ?? 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                
                // Option 1: VStack and HStack
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<rowNr+1) { row in
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(0..<colNr+1) { col in
                                // find cell with row + col numbers
                                if let cell = tableData.first(where: { $0.rowIndex == row && $0.columnIndex == col }) {
                                    Text(cell.text)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Divider()
                
                // Option 2: LazyVGrid View
                let columns = [GridItem].init(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 10)), count: colNr+1)
                    
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    ForEach(tableData
                        .sorted(by: {$0.columnIndex < $1.columnIndex})
                        .sorted(by: {$0.rowIndex < $1.rowIndex}))
                    { cell in
                        Text(cell.text)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
As @loremipsum pointed out there might be the case, that there is no value for every combination of row/columns. In this case you could map the data to an array first, filling the empty data points:

```
    func dataMappedToArray() -> [Cell] {
        
        let rowNr = tableData.reduce(0, { max($0, $1.rowIndex) })
        let colNr = tableData.reduce(0, { max($0, $1.columnIndex) })

        var result = [Cell]()
        for row in 0...rowNr {
            for col in 0...colNr {
                if let cell = tableData.first(where: { $0.rowIndex == row && $0.columnIndex == col }) {
                    result.append(cell)
                } else {
                    // "empty" cell
                    result.append(Cell(rowIndex: row, columnIndex: col, text: "–", boundingBox: [], isHeader: nil) )
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: This assumes that there is a value for every column/row.

Comment: Good workaround but what if there are duplicate values? It is just a very fragile setup. Not giving you a hard time. Because after you come up with a solution for that I would ask what if it is a large dataset? creating the dataset, sorting, inserting dummies and everything else in the `body` is a lot of work.